# How can I disable this GTK3 scrollbar behaviour?

Tags: xfce, gui, gtk, scrolling, gtk3

When I click for longer than a second on a scrollbar slider in a GTK3 program, it becomes narrow and the scrolling becomes ridiculously slow.

I know that this is intentional, but I find it **really annoying**.

I cannot find any instructions on how to disable this behaviour. Can anyone help?

Comment: I didn't find a config option to turn it off but here's a patch https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7705894.html

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/927161 indicates that the patch may just translate to a settings.ini line...